# InvalidArchiveError when installing openssl-1.1.1g through Anaconda 4.7.12 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-requests, openssl, anaconda

I am trying to install requests module, and openssl keep causing the InvalidArchiveError.
I am using conda 4.7.12, python 3.8.2, on Windows 10 operating system. I had the same issue when installing other packages requiring openssl-1.1.1g. I have followed the advice from the error message to delete and re-download 'openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2', but I keep getting the same error.
Is this version of openssl broken or something? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
lykim@Louis MINGW64 ~/Desktop/master/Learning
$ conda install -c anaconda requests
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.8.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch

  added / updated specs:
    - requests


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    openssl-1.1.1g             |       he774522_0         5.8 MB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         5.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  brotlipy           conda-forge/win-64::brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h1e8a9f7_1000
  cffi               anaconda/win-64::cffi-1.14.0-py38h7a1dbc1_0
  chardet            anaconda/win-64::chardet-3.0.4-py38_1003
  cryptography       anaconda/win-64::cryptography-2.9.2-py38h7a1dbc1_0
  idna               anaconda/noarch::idna-2.9-py_1
  pycparser          anaconda/noarch::pycparser-2.20-py_0
  pyopenssl          anaconda/win-64::pyopenssl-19.1.0-py38_0
  pysocks            anaconda/win-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py38_0
  requests           anaconda/win-64::requests-2.23.0-py38_0
  urllib3            conda-forge/noarch::urllib3-1.25.9-py_0
  win_inet_pton      anaconda/win-64::win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py38_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2020.4.5.1-py38h~ --> anaconda::certifi-2020.4.5.1-py38_0
  openssl                                       conda-forge --> anaconda


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
openssl-1.1.1g       | 5.8 MB    | ########## | 100%

InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')

(pytorch)
```

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same problem a couple of times. This time my problem was solved simply by closing down jupyter notebook, which was running and using openssl, so if your python is running somewhere, try to close it down. (In addition had already removed openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2 and a number of folders openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0 containing also those .tar balls, so that might be necessary as well)

Answer (score 2):

You may try to go to your packages directory

> `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\`

Then delete `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2` file,  install `libarchive` and reinstall your package.

---

#### Another Solution

---

Simply you can install on your anaconda environment using pip instead of conda, anyway i recommend to update your conda too.

Comment: I have tried deleting and reinstalling `openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0.tar.bz2` but I still get the same error. I have also tried deleting, installing `libarchive`, then reinstalling, but I still get the same error.

Comment: could you try to update your conda `conda update -n base conda` or  clean by `conda clean -a`

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error, I think it was caused by an earlier failed installation which had left an incomplete openssl-1.1.1g-he774522_0 directory in users\username\Anaconda3\pkgs. Just delete it and then it completes just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I installed tensoflow-gpu and this happen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There was some "openssl*" folders. Deleted them, and the "openssl*" .bz2 files as well, and tried to install again. Now works perfectly.

Eventually the folders can't be deleted because they're used by other programs. If it happens, go to Task Manager and close python.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my error by elevating my command window. The delete method wasn't working.